# Can you run PySimpleGUI functions interactively through Python console?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pysimplegui

I believe the best way for me to debug something or to gain more understanding of it would be to be able to just insert command in the console and than see the output in the GUI.

I have tried to run with Python Console and disabling the infinite event loop, however this returns an unresponsive GUI.

I have also tried to set a debug point in PyCharm and than run expression than, but the same thing happens the GUI freezes.

Is there a way for me to just initialize the GUI and than run commands? I am mostly interested in using the update function for several elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why call PySimleGUI code interactively.

Interactive with PySimpleGUI code as following, call `window.refresh()` if sometime some code not update immediately.

```py
>>> import PySimpleGUI as sg
>>> layout = [[sg.Text("", size=(40, 1), key='TEXT')],[sg.Button("Change")]]
>>> window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)
>>> t = window['TEXT']
>>> t.update(value="Hello World")
>>> t.update(value="Goodbye")
>>> window.close()
>>> quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, it is just quite often the interface freezes.